# Hide div until file selected

Tags: jquery

I have an image upload form with the following element:

```
<input type="file">
```

I need to hide a div and only show it when a file is selected.

```
$("#myDiv").hide();
```

Do I need to add an ID to the form element and do onchange check if it's !empty? Not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    $("#myDiv").show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/eVSxD/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should do that. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3WSTd/

Answer (score 1):

Yes

http://jsfiddle.net/XdsLP/

The selector for the input doesn't matter.

Comment: @Tandu what if the selector for the input does matter? What if it includes a "Image caption" field? Populating that field would trigger your code.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I meant to say you can use any selector you want as long as it matches the desired input(s)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add an id to the input element but if you are showing a specific div if this particular element is populated, then I'd assign the behavior to an id instead of what @Neal suggested, as his solution will show the div regardless of what input file field was populated.

```
$('#my_file').change(function(){
    if(this.value != '')
    {
        $('#my_div').fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#my_div').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Gq3Jf/